# Как в js выполнить действие над всеми элементами с одним классом?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Подскажите, как делается, чтобы цвет при наведении изменялся у каждой "a" этого класса, а не только у первой(интересует именно через js).

```
    <a class="test" href="#">link-1</a>
    <a class="test" href="#">link-2</a>
    <a class="test" href="#">link-3</a>

    <script>

        let link = document.querySelector('.test')
        link.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            link.style.color = "red"
        })

    </script>

</body>
```

решение-вот:

````
    <a class="test" href="#">link-1</a>
    <a class="test" href="#">link-2</a>
    <a class="test" href="#">link-3</a>

    <script>

        let link = document.querySelectorAll('.test')
        for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
  link[i].onclick = function(){
    alert("ASPAS");
//    что здесь написать, чтобы изменить цвет?
  };
}
 </script>

</body>```


 alert работает. но как мне добавить вместо него изменение цвета?
````

Comment: Использовать querySelectorAll вместо querySelector?

Comment: Пробовал - не работает.

Comment: Вешать обработчик на каждый элемент отдельно - это bad practice. Его нужно вешать общий родительский элемент. 
window.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
 if(e.target.classList.contains('название_класа')) {
   // Действие
  }
})